# Use question mark operator when calling method on possible null value?

Tags: dart

I have a varible containing an object which might be null. When trying to call a method I have to check for null. I want the result to be false if the variable is null. What is considered good and readable style to to this?

e.g.

```
class MyClass {
  bool boolMethod() {
    return true;
  }
}

void main() {
  MyClass mc = new MyClass();
  MyClass mcnull = null;

  bool val1 = mc?.boolMethod();
  bool val1null = mcnull?.boolMethod();

  bool val2 = mc != null && mc.boolMethod();
  bool val2null = mcnull != null && mcnull.boolMethod();
}
```

Especially when used in if-statements I consider the first version much more readable:

```
if (mc?.boolMethod())...
```

versus

```
if (mc != null && mc.boolMethod())...
```

But IntelliJ gives me the hint *The value of the '?.' operator can be 'null' which isn't appropriate as an operand of a locaical operator.* (null_aware_in_logical_operator). Ok - this is right because when the variable is null then I use the null as a boolean value. But it's ok in my case and I try to avoid suppressing warnings.

What is the suggested way? Other ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think a common pattern is

```
  bool val1 = (mc?.boolMethod() ?? false);
```

The parens aren't required here but if such expressions are embedded into more complex expressions they are often necessary to get the expected behavior because of the low priority of `??`

Comment: Thank you. It's not as nice as I hoped, but this might be the best way.